# Trouble getting Typed.js blinking cursor inside form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, typed

Using the Typed.js jQuery plugin, I have been trying to get the blinking cursor to appear inside the form input. I have tried messing around with it and even copying examples that I found online exactly, but it still appears outside the form input. Any ideas?

here is a fiddle showing the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/dunphyben/1pp3x3au/1/

```
$(function(){
    $(".form-control").typed({
        strings: ["Web Developer", "Graphic Designer", "Mobile Developer", "Road Warrior", "DevOps", "Real Estate Agent", "Accountant", "Product Manager", "CEO"],
        attr: "placeholder",
        typeSpeed: 100
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

remove the blinking css animation and add an empty string using quotations, like so:

,""

at the end of the cycle you'll have a blinking cursor.

```
$(function(){
    $(".form-control").typed({
        strings: ["Web Developer", "pimp", ""],
        attr: "placeholder",
        typeSpeed: 100
    });
});
```

UPDATED fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1pp3x3au/16/

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i'm looking to get the blinking cursor _inside_ the text box, not make it disappear completely. also, the cursor does not appear at the end of the cycle

Comment: that forces the cursor to be on the left, rather than move with the text. it should look like the example on the tool's site http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Comment: this is tricky. I didn't find a solution. Cosmetically, it's not a big deal. I actually prefer not having a blinking cursor while typed.js runs.

Comment: every example i've seen using typed.js has the blinking cursor in the right spot. it must be something silly that i'm missing

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post and you may not even be using this anymore, but you just need to float your holding class left:

```
.yourclass {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: were u successful adding that to the js fiddle above? i tried it, and didn't work. this is so weird...lots of people used typed.js and don't have this problem. i must be missing something, but i followed all the docs to the T.

Comment: @BenjaminDunphy updated here: https://jsfiddle.net/1pp3x3au/24/ your .form-control is pushing the cursor to the right of the box.

Comment: thanks mate. getting the blinker inside the box is a step in the right direction. but most applications of typed.js show the cursor at the end of the text, moving with the text as it is typed/deleted.